# Finding a complete theory which contains the theory of sentences that hold for every finite field.

Tags: model-theory

I am trying to make some exercises for a introductory course to mathematical logic.

Let $T$ be the theory consisting of all sentences that are true in every finite field. It is not that hard to see that this is a consistent, but not a complete theory. I am being asked to give a concrete example of theory which contains $T$, but which is complete.

I know that I will need to add a sentence for every <s>cardinality</s> characteristic ,but I am unsure if this is enough to make the theory complete. If it is not I do not know how to give a concrete theory which is even larger.

I also thought about taking the set of all sentences that are true in a specific model of $T$, but again I do not know how to show completeness.

Comment: It seems that you think that you should add $\varphi_n$ for every $n$ saying that "if there are $n$ elements, then their complete diagram is that of $\Bbb F_n$", but note that this will not be enough since your theory has infinite models as well.

Comment: Doesn't $T\cup\{$" there exist exactly two elements"$\}$ work?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I was actually thinking of fixing the characteristic by adding sentences like $\neg(1+1+\ldots+1=0)$. I edited my main post.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I am not sure how you can show that every sentence or its negation is provable.

Comment: @David: That's an easy cop-out. :-)

Comment: @Jarne: Since the characteristics does not determine the field, that's definitely not going to work. As for David's comment, if you have only two elements, then you have exactly one model of the theory, so it is necessarily complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wrote:

> I also thought about taking the set of all sentences that are true in a specific model of $T$, but again I do not know how to show completeness.

This is the easiest way to pick a completion of a consistent theory $T$. Let $M\models T$ and consider $$T' = \text{Th}(M) = \{\varphi\mid M\models \varphi\}.$$ The completeness of $T'$ is obvious - there's almost nothing to show. $T'$ is consistent, since $M\models T'$. And for any sentence $\psi$, either $M\models \psi$ or $M\models \lnot \psi$, so either $\psi$ or $\lnot\psi$ is in $T'$, so $T'$ is complete.

In fact, every completion of $T$ has this form. If $T'$ is a complete consistent theory extending $T$, then letting $M\models T'$, we have $T' = \text{Th}(M)$.

Ok, but your exercise asks you to give a *concrete* example of a completion of $T$. This is the problem with the strategy above. For a given model $M$, it may be hard (if not impossible) to give a concrete axiomatization of $\text{Th}(M)$.

Let's specialize now to the situation in your exercise, where $T$ is the theory consisting of all sentences which are true in every finite field. As pointed out in the comments, there's an easy way to axiomatize a complete consistent theory extending $T$: For every prime $p$ and natural number $n>0$, there is a unique finite field of cardinality $p^n$ up to isomorphism. So letting $T'$ be the field axioms together with a sentence asserting that a model has exactly $p^n$ elements, $T'$ has a unique model up to isomorphism. And it is clear that a theory with exactly one model up to isomorphism is consistent and complete.

Ok, can we solve your exercise in a less trivial way, by writing down a complete theory extending $T$ that has infinite models? It turns out the answer is yes, but it's pretty complicated and relies on some deep work by James Ax: [The Elementary Theory of Finite fields (1968)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970573?origin=crossref&seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents).

To begin with, Ax axiomatized the theory $T$: the models of $T$ are called [pseudo-finite fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-finite_field). These are characterized as fields which are perfect (i.e., have characteristic $0$, or have characteristic $p$ and every element has a $p^{\text{th}}$ root), have absolute Galois group $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ (equivalently, have a unique algebraic extension of degree $n$ for each $n$), and are [pseudo algebraically closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_algebraically_closed_field). It is not immediately obvious that these conditions can be written down as first-order sentences in the language of fields, but with a little work they can be.

Now Ax also proved that two pseudo-finite fields $K$ and $L$ are elementarily equivalent if and only if $\text{Abs}(K) \cong \text{Abs}(L)$, where $\text{Abs}(F)$ is the relative algebraic closure of the prime field inside $F$, i.e., those elements of $F$ which are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ in characteristic $0$ and over $\mathbb{F}_p$ in characteristic $p$. Now the isomorphism type of an algebraic extension $E$ of a perfect field $F$ is determined by which polynomials in $F[x]$ have roots in $E$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2930995/algebraic-extensions-are-isomorphic-if-the-same-polynomials-have-roots)). So we can axiomatize the complete theory of a pseudo-finite field $K$ by writing down:

1. The axioms of pseudo-finite fields.
2. Axioms fixing the characteristic ($0$ or a prime $p$).
3. Letting $F$ be the prime subfield of $K$, axioms specifying which polynomials in $F[x]$ have roots in $K$.

Comment: What. An. **Excellent**. Answer.